# Uploaded images to mysql database, but can I retrieve it for an edit page?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}


$fileName_th = $_FILES['thumbnail']['name'];
$tmpName_th  = $_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize_th = $_FILES['thumbnail']['size'];
$fileType_th = $_FILES['thumbnail']['type'];


$fp_th      = fopen($tmpName_th, 'r');
$content_th = fread($fp_th, filesize($tmpName_th));
$content_th = addslashes($content_th);
fclose($fp_th);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName_th = addslashes($fileName_th);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO Images (profile_id, thumb, name, size, type, content ) ".
"VALUES ('$profile_id', 0, '$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content'),('$profile_id', 1, '$fileName_th', '$fileSize_th', '$fileType_th', '$content_th') ";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);


echo "<br>$first_name uploaded successfully";
```

That is the method im using to upload my images to my database. Now, what I want to do is to have an edit page which edits my form elements like text, along with making changes to the images.

I know how to query text elements and place them back into their  respective input fields, but how do i do that for files like images?

Side question: What is the best way of "uploading" files to the database? Is it my way? Or is there a way of just writing files to a directory and saving the path in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.  You can't in the same sense as text elements as potentially the image would not exist at the same location as you have stored if you are accessing the interface on a different computer.

When I've seen this kind of requirement in the past, the stored image is normally simply displayed and an option to replace/remove it is given.  Unlike a text input, you're never going to change part of the image, you're going to change the whole thing so there's no need to provide the stored image path for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific need to store the file the way you are, one fairly straightforward solution would be to upload the files to a webserver (but not directly to the database) and simply store the *link* to them (this is what I've done for a podcasting solution, using mp3s rather than images, but much of the idea is the same). With the link, you could simply use `<img>` tags in your layout where the `src` field is populated from the information you dropped in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve them to the client as an [image type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types). Generally, I would implement a view (or page, depending on your terminology ;)) that is used to query for and render the image. For example: http://myurl.com/index.php/images/index/id/[db image pkey] (that is, if you're using an MVC framework such as [CI](http://codeigniter.com/), otherwise you can use any .php file to achieve the same result).

Using the example URL, the controller (images) would be responsible for instantiating an image model that queries the database for the image with the pkey specified in the URL. The view (or page) would take the data result from the model, simply set the Content-type header to whatever the image content type is, and then serve the binary image data to the client.

AFAIK, there's no way to achieve this inline when you're rendering the rest of your form data as it's a different MIME type.

Edit: Having said the above, after a little reading, it seems that you might not want to do this anyway (read [this](http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/36-Serving-Images-From-A-Database.html) for further details as to why not). It would be better to store them as static images on the file system.

Comment: Good example how to display inline images are there http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks. Not sure how I feel about it yet though ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need just add header like this **image.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['image']) && $_GET['image'] > 0) {
   //Connect to the database
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
   mysql_select_db("database");

   //Select image content
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `content`, `type` FROM `Images` WHERE profile_id = ".(int)$_GET['image']." LIMIT 1");
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

   //Just display the image and finish the application
   header("Content-type: image/{$row['type']}");
   die($row['content']);
}
?>
```

There can be some bugs. The main thing is to send the proper headers.
To that image you can access with  tag like this:

```
<img src="image.php?image=1" alt="" />
```

But if you want to display image in the same scene you need encode that to base64 and display inline like this:

```
//Imagine that we already got content from the database
$row['content'] = base64_encode($row['content']);

//Prepare inline image
$row['content'] = "data:image/{$row['type']};base64,".$row['content'];

//You will get something like this
/*
data:image/png;base64,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%3D
*/

echo "<img src=\"{$row['content']}\" />";
```